# Find exact match with Range.Find in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms, find

I made a function, but somehow even though I tried `xlPrevious` and `xlNext` as `XLSearchDirection` Parameter of `Range.Find` it always finds the same cell.

```
private string ColumnFinder(Excel.Worksheet searchOn, string searchForWhat, int optRow = 4)
        {
            int col = -1;
            try
            {
                col = searchOn.Range[optRow + ":" + optRow].Find(searchForWhat, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value).Column;
            }
            catch (Exception exSearch)
            {
                //Debugging
                //MessageBox.Show("Couldn't find \"" + searchForWhat + "\" in row " + optRow + " on sheet " + searchOn.Name);

                return String.Empty;
            }
            return ConvertColumnIndexToLetter(col);
        }
```

I call the function like this:

```
string col = ColumnFinder(ws, "Used");
```

It's supposed to find column A where the value is "Used" and not column L where the value is "Used at picture…"

Comment: it's not odd - if you don't specify the column like in my case, then it takes the entire row (which is 4, as you said)

Comment: Use `LookAt:=xlWhole` if you want to match the entire cell contents. Otherwise `Range.Find` will return any cell that _contains_ "Used" (e.g. "Used at picture...", "..was used at...", etc.)